# what is the use of thisvalue in javascript array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

```
array.map(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)

array.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

why is the use of thisValue?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map *"Value to use as `this` when executing `callbackFn`"*

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good place for this type of question (which is "Please provide a list of hypothetical problems that this language feature can solve"). There isn't a measurably correct answer to that type of question.

Comment: Value to use as this when executing callbackFn, what does that really means?

Answer (score 1):

Because of [how the `this` keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/476), you'd lose the context when you do something like:

```
array.map(this.callback)
```

The workaround would be:

```
array.map(this.callback.bind(this))
```

The `thisValue` is a more elegant way to do that:

```
array.map(this.callback, this)
```

And you can use it for your own purposes if you want, `this` doesn't need to be the original `this`:

```
/**
 * Accepts a callback and returns the array mapped over this callback.
 * The `this` context inside the callback will be set to someElement,
 * you can use it to influence your callback's return value.
 */
function foo(callback) {
    return array.map(callback, someElement)
}
```